# How to search a JSON API and decode an array using AlamoFire

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift4

I am searching a JSON API and I need to decode an array inside of it. I am using AlamoFire. Example: When I type in the letter "F" I want only the "F" word to display. I would like to search only in the array "name". Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

This is my code below:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let url = "http://dummy.com/url"
    Alamofire.request(url).responseData { (dataResponse) in
        if let err = dataResponse.error {
            print("Failed to contact", err)
            return
        }

        guard let data = dataResponse.data else { return }
        let dummyString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print(dummyString ?? "")

        do {
             let searchResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(SearchResults.self, from: data)
            print("Result Count:", searchResult.id)

        } catch let decodeError {
            print("Failed to decode:", decodeError)
        }
    }
}

struct SearchResults: Decodable {
    let id: String

}
```

**My API array looks like this:**

{
resultId: "1",
name: "Food",
},
{
resultId: "2",
name: "Movies",
}

Comment: What is the actual response you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is in `array` `format` so you need to put your `model` like this:

```
let searchResult = try JSONDecoder().decode([SearchResults].self, from: data)
```

And for search, you can apply filters:

```
let filteredArray = searchResult.filter( { $0.name.contains("f") } )
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Can we go to a chat to discuss this more?

Comment: Yes sure, we can go

Comment: How can we go to a chat on this

Comment: I think there is a chat on stackoverflow

Comment: You can ask here also

Comment: If I ask a question, it will make us go to a chat haha

Comment: hopefully it comes up soon so we can chat

Comment: It will auto come when comments are more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170881/discussion-between-jogendar-choudhary-and-box-house).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your response is:

```
[
 { resultId: "1", name: "Food" }, 
 { resultId: "2", name: "Movies"}
]
```

So, your struct would be,

```
struct SearchResults: Decodable {
    let resultId: String
    let name: String
}
```

And you will use it as:

```
    do {
        let resultArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([SearchResults].self, from: data)
        print("Result Count:", searchResult.id)

    } catch let decodeError {
        print("Failed to decode:", decodeError)
    }
```

For searching, you should use `filter`, as:

```
    let searchString = "F"
    let filteredArray = resultArray.filter( { String($0.name.first!) == searchString } )
```

> **For matching first character** = String($0.name.first!) == searchText
>
> **Check if name has search Text** = $0.name.contains(searchText)

**In total:**

```
    do {
        let searchResult = try JSONDecoder().decode([SearchResults].self, from: data)
        let filteredArray = resultArray.filter( { $0.name.contains(searchText) } )
    } catch let decodeError {
        print("Failed to decode:", decodeError)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I would like to search by any letter that I clicked on the keyboard. How can I do that? I was giving "F" as an example

Comment: Can we go to a chat to discuss this?